# How to send POST request to another node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I make 2 servers

```
var express = require('express');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var data = querystring.stringify({
    username: 'myname',
    password: 'pass'
  });

  var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8081,
    path: '/demo',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
  };

  var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      res.send('ok');
    })
  });
  httpreq.write(data);
  httpreq.end();
});

app.listen(8090, function(){
    console.log('Server start on 8090');
});
```

The second one is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/demo', function(req, res){
    console.log('Body : ', req.body);
});

app.listen(8081, function(){
    console.log('Server Start on 8081');
});
```

I want to send the data from localhost:8090 to the localhost:8081.

But at the 2nd server side when I try to print req.body It shows me

```
Server Start on 8081
Body :  undefined
```

Help me to find solution. And If you have better code then this then it will good for me.

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your body is undefined in your express server is because you're not using the [`body-parser`](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware. Express cannot parse request body's for the Content-Type `x-www-form-urlencoded` like you have specified in your request. Also in your request you're not sending in data through the body of your request, you're sending it in the query string, so your Express Route needs to check the query string and not the body.

You'll need to make your Express look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }); // Parse x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/demo', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Query String: ${req.query}`);
  console.log(`Body: ${req.body}`);
});

app.listen(port, () => { 
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`); 
});
```

Comment: I hate this silly mistakes. Sorry for that. And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do request like this

```
require('request').post(
    "localhost:8081/demo", 
    {form: 
        {
            username: "name",
            password: "any"
        }
    },
    function(error, response, body){
        console.log(body);
    }
);
```

Comment: can you give me a demo example?

Comment: @MithilAmin what data do you need to send?

Comment: Just send username: 'name', password:'any'

Comment: This code will send the data to localhost:8081/demo right?

Comment: @MithilAmin it will send the data and log the response body

Comment: var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
        require('request').post("localhost:8081/demo", {
        username: 'Mithil', 
        password: 'any'
    }, function(err, res, body){

    })
});

app.listen(8080);

Comment: I want to receive the body parameter at the localhost:8081.